# openCV moveWindow, not moving

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi4

I've connected two USB cameras to a Raspberry Pi4. Using OpenCV I'm able to stream the videos from both cameras simultaneously, however I'd like to position the video windows in a specific location on the monitor. When the windows are displayed I can use the mouse to "drag" each window to a location on the monitor. Below is the basic script I'm using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

capture0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture1 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

cv2.namedWindow("Cam 0", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow("Cam 1", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.resizeWindow("Cam 0", 640, 480)
cv2.resizeWindow("Cam 1", 640, 480)

cv2.moveWindow("Cam 0",0,0)
cv2.moveWindow("Cam 1",680,0)

while True:
    ret0, frame0 = capture0.read()
    ret1, frame1 = capture1.read()
    
    if (ret0):
       cv2.imshow("Cam 0", frame0)
            
    if (ret1):
       cv2.imshow("Cam 1", frame1)
            
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

capture0.release()
capture1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It doesn't matter what coordinates I put in the "moveWindow" command, "Cam 0" appears in the center of the screen and "Cam 1" seems to randomly appear in different locations each time I run the script.
Any ideas what I'm doing incorrectly?
Thanks Brian!

Comment: works fine on Windows. can *anyone* reproduce this? on what system?

Comment: Update: I revised the script by removing the "if" statements for both "imshow" commands, moved the moveWindow command under each imshow.  Ran the revised script on the Pi4 running OpenCV V4.6.0 and it still places one window in the center and the other is on top the first window slightly. Ran the same script on a Jetson Nano, running Ubuntu 20 and OpenCV 4.8.0 and it works as desired; windows can be positioned.